# Trouble creating dataframe using pandas: ValueError/data type not understood

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a bit new to pandas/numpy and have had trouble with this issue.

I have a group of 10 lists, each of which have 58 elements in them (strings). When I try to join them into a dataframe

```
df = pd.Dataframe(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
```

I get the error `"ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 58), indices imply (58, 58)"`

I started trying different combinations of the lists to check which list was causing the problem (I checked types and len etc.) and then I started getting the error "data type not understood".

I've tried checking similar posts but nothing has been working for me so far. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
df = pd.Dataframe([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j])
```

The difference

```
# You had
df = pd.Dataframe( a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j )
#                  ^ \________________________/
#                  |              |
#      data argument              |
#                 stuff pandas thought was something else

# New code
df = pd.Dataframe([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j])
#                 \____________________________/ 
#                                |
#                          data argument
```

The first argument represents the data.  According to python, you were passing 10 arguments, only the first, `a`, was getting interpreted as the data argument.  The way I've told you to do it, all those elements are passed within a list `[]` and it is that list that pandas will take as the data argument, which is what I think you want.

Comment: thank you so much! could you explain why this worked compared to what I did earlier?

Comment: The explanation is in the post.  I'll make it clearer.